# Blender 2.8 - When I rotate a bone, the entire mesh deforms

Tags: rigging, armature, eevee-render-engine

I just made the switch to Blender 2.8, but I have encountered a problem. I followed CG Geek's tutorial on how to make a low poly human mesh, but I encounter a problem when I rig the mesh.
[image]

But when I try to move the hip bone, this happens.
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like a weighting problem. Did you use automatic weights? You might need to tidy them up by hand, or add the rest of the Bones so Blender knows what it's doing.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thank you.